# How can I serve assets from different cloud service buckets by website domain in angular index file

Tags: angular, assets, cdn

The goal is to serve image & font assets from two cloud service buckets (AWS) and (ALIYUN) due to political reasons.

Chinese clients do not want to view images/fonts from an american service in AWS so we need to instead serve them from ALIYUN.

Thus the angular website will be serving assets from AWS when the domain is not china and from Aliyun when it is.

So far my strategy involves in using a domain base variable in a global scss file. This variable will prepend all assets url in SCSS files 
so it will look something like:

domain.scss file

$domain-asset: https://s3-amazon.myBucket/;

This scss file will be overwritten during the project build process (using node's writefile) so that if we instead switch to china, the file will now have
on build completion the following:

domain.scss file

$domain-asset: https://aliyun.oss.myBucket/;

This works well for assets in scss files, however when assets like favicon and pre-rendered fonts are declared in the index.html, the context is out
of the scss files. Is there anyway I can set the base domain on them as well?

I looked at angular.json configuration, the 'deploy-url' property came closest to what I would like except that url is prepended in absolutely
all assets in the index file (css and js files included) but its not those files that will be living in the cloud, just the favicons and fonts.

Answer (score 1):

So far what I have come up with, is using read/write node.js fs to edit files with the right bucket base url, based on a command line parameter we created 'cloud' to set to either aws or alibaba on angular build command. 
- For assets in the index file. I modify the file with the help of JSDOM (which emmulates DOM manipulation), find all links (with the JSDOM queryselector) with the word 'assets', and prefix the url accordingly. 
- For images in the scss files, I read/write a global scss stylesheet that contains the variable that holds the url domain.

This works nicely until both buckets are multiplied by five to accommodate different environments, e.g development, quality, staging etc... Setting the environment in the url becomes problematic if it is done on build because now whoever builds the project has to be conscious of which environment it is destined to. If we build development images and deploy on quality by mistake, this would be an unintended occurrence.

Next thing to try is to have at least the stylesheets deployed to the buckets, that way all images can rely on relative path and there is no need to determine what bucket url is needed. So far I'm not sure how this will be implemented.